# Intl.DisplayNames in Chrome not working with 3-letter codes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internationalization

I'm looking for feedback / workarounds for a problem I'm encountering when trying to use the new `Intl.DisplayNames` API to translate language names in Google Chrome.

According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=Intl.DisplayNames) it is fully supported in Chrome, which is confirmed in the [V8 dev page](https://v8.dev/features/intl-displaynames). The language codes are supposed to follow the [Unicode language identifier](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Unicode_language_identifier) specification.  The Unicode language identifiers are defined in [BCP47](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt) and modeled after `ISO 639`, if I'm not mistaken. For example: High Middle German has the identifier `gmh` in the [CLDR](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/f6acf4462b9f42065b6e4f3a347911bfe1ae748d/common/main/en.xml#L225).

The translated language name can be retrieved in JS with the following code snippet:

```js
new Intl.DisplayNames(['en'], { type: 'language' }).of('gmh')
// Output in Chrome 91: "gmh"
// Output in Firefox 90: "Middle High German"
// Output in Safari 14.1: "Middle High German"
```

As noted in the output of the snippet above, this works as expected in Firefox and Safari, in Chrome this only seems to work for languages with two letter language codes similar to ISO 639-1 like `de` for `German` but not three letter language codes similar to ISO 639-2 like `gmh` for `High Middle German`.

I couldn't find an issue relating to this in the Chromium issue tracker. Is there a solution to this that doesn't come down to me implementing this functionality manually? If I'm not mistaken, a polyfill won't work as Chrome does indeed implement Intl.DisplayNames, it's just not following the full spec.

Comment: You are confusing two things: one is about the format (Chrome allows 3 letters), but the issue is different: it is about having a list of all languages (which it is an impossible task). Chrome just choose a different (and possibly small) set of languages.

Comment: Workaround: just implement yourself the database (or look for a library). Better to implement important stuffs, instead of relying on browser to implement functions (this is true for most of Unicode, localisation and font stuffs)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I see what you mean with "confusing two things" by the spec  stating that the identifier can be something following the Unicode language tags but not guaranteeing that you will get a usable result for it. However that makes the system much less useful outside of very simple requirements as developers cannot rely on it if they need more than ISO 639-1 even if it is already part of ISO and Unicode data. For me it means, I have to do the same thing as Firefox probably does: copy the definitions from the Unicode language files and use them as a basis of the translation myself.

Comment: Yes, the standard tell you that you can use that function, but not much more. Then it is "quality of implementation". Unicode data still lacks of many locales (it is working in progress, and it will requires a lot more years), and final result (with all Unicode properties) will be very huge, for just small usage. "Middle High German" is also standard specific (not sure if it is used by linguistics, and you may want the term in German). When you go outside the large base of users, you often you should implement things yourself (or patch libraries). [Note: sometime is delegation to OS, so worse]